# GitHub Pages falhando ao tentar carregar recursos com error 404

Tags: html, css, github

Tentei subir um projeto que havia feito há algum tempo, e ao usar as páginas do GitHub para reproduzir online, deparo-me com dificuldades na renderização.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os arquivos dos quais ele não consegue carregar estão todos no [repositório](https://github.com/jcavalcantef/projetoGlass/), não entendo a dificuldade que as páginas do GitHub estão tendo para serem renderizadas.

Eis aqui uma  [pergunta semelhante no StackOverflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40448288/8748688) mostrando um problema similar, mas diferente da minha pelo fato de não ter usado Jekyll.

> Aqui está um exemplo de como a página deveria ser renderizada, veja que em localhost funciona perfeitamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> A figura abaixo mostra como a página é exibida via [acesso remoto](https://jcavalcantef.github.io/projetoGlass/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Ao analisar o problema, reparei que o link onde o css fica,  é diferente de onde realmente está localizado via url, observe-se abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É normal essa url **não** bater com o caminho real do arquivo `estilo.css`?

Alguém pode ajudar como resolver esse problema, em relação a falha de carregamento dos recursos em páginas do GitHub?

Comment: Mas esses arquivos existem no branch `gh-pages`?

Comment: Sim, esse resultado aparece tanto no brach master quanto no gh-pages

Comment: Coloca a parte do código onde você está importando os .Css

Comment: Da pra ver todos os códigos através do link que eu coloquei na pergunta que leva ao repositório, eu to suspeitando que o motivo é por causa dos recursos "pesados" como vídeo e fotos que não estão carregando e gerando a maior parte do error 404

Comment: Nossa, nem tinha reparado... Cara, não sei por que, mas estou achando que é esse underline no nome das pastas... tenta tirar o underline do nome das pastas

Comment: já alterei e até agora nenhum resultado =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema foi resolvido com a retirada do ***underline*** no nome de cada pasta, não havia percebido antes pois o carregamento das páginas demorava pra carregar e tive que retirar esse caracter de todas os arquivos, o que demorou um pouco.

Não sei dizer porque isso causa o problema de falha no carregamento do conteúdo, mas aparentemente resolveu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema nada tem haver com a quantidade de fotos ou vídeos carregados, eles de fato pesam mas não impedem o carregamento da página.

> Fica a dica: Quem colocar nome da pasta com underline **não vai funcionar**
>
> > Exemplo: _css ou _javascript